# RDFlib with Fuseki running queries very slowly on local server

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib, fuseki

I have a small wsgi app, running a local Cherry server, and I use the RDFlib to turn human language queries into SPARQL queries for querying a ttl file loaded to fuseki. It works, but it is incredibly slow! The previous version of this script accepted SPARQL queries directly, so I didn't use the RDFlib, and it worked very fast! Is there is something wrong with the way I use RDFlib which makes it so slow??

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty
from collections import OrderedDict
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from cherrypy import engine
from cherrypy.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
from werkzeug.wsgi import SharedDataMiddleware
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response, Request
from requests import get, post, RequestException
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import os
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
import rdflib


__author__ = 'authorname'

templates_dir = os.path.abspath('templates')
static_dir = os.path.abspath('static')

class RdfDemoApp(object):
    def __init__(self, sparql_endpoint_address):
        self._sparql_endpoint_address = sparql_endpoint_address
        self._jinja_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(templates_dir), autoescape=True)

    def render_template(self, template, **params):
        t = self._jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def _app(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        if 'query' in request.args.keys():
            query_string = "'"+request.args['query']+"'"
            print query_string

            results = g.query("""PREFIX pers: <http://blabla.com/Register/schemas/persons/>
            SELECT ?person ?sibling ?sibforname
            WHERE { 
               ?person pers:name ?name .
                 ?name  pers:forename """+query_string+""" .
                ?person pers:siblingOf ?sibling .
                ?sibling pers:name ?sibname .
                ?sibname pers:forename ?sibforname .
                 ?sibname pers:type "std"  } """)#, format = "JSON")
            for row in results:
                print row
            header = []
            i=0
            for item in results:
                while i in range(len(item)):
                    for x in item:
                        header.append(x)
                        i+=1
            quer = query_string
            response = Response(self.render_template('results_rdf.html', results=results, header = header, query = quer, static_dir = static_dir ), mimetype='text/html')

        else:
            response = Response(self.render_template('form_rdf.html'), mimetype='text/html')

        return response(environ, start_response)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        app = SharedDataMiddleware(DebuggedApplication(self._app, evalex=True), {
            '/static': static_dir
        })
        return app(environ, start_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g=rdflib.Graph()
    g.parse("/Users/username/Documents/pers_file_new.ttl", format='n3')
    wsgi_app = RdfDemoApp("http://localhost:3030/ds/query")
    try:
        server = CherryPyWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1',10001), wsgi_app)
        server.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()
        print "Logged out"
```

Comment: Same question as http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/31334/rdflib-with-fuseki-running-queries-very-slowly-on-local-server

Comment: and no answer so far. I posted it here as well for a better visibility.

Comment: @user3241376 It's OK to crosspost, but it's good etiquette to let us know;  that way we could skim answers there to see it it's already been answered, or so that others who find this question and need an answer have another place to look.  Stack Overflow is designed to be helpful to *everyone* who finds the question, not just the original asker.

Comment: Should I have put a link to the semweb post to let you know? If so, I will do it next time. So far I deleted the semweb post, there were no answers anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how large your dataset in pers_file_new.ttl is but one reason for it being slow is that you are reading it all into memory using RDFLib.

`g.parse("/Users/username/Documents/pers_file_new.ttl", format='n3')`

With your current code, you aren't querying Fuseki but an in memory RDFLib graph.  You could follow the example from the SPARQLWrapper home page.  It's pretty close to what you are trying to do.

http://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/

Comment: my turtle file is not big at all, about 80000 triples. I was guessing that I use the graph "g" separately from fuseki, though I have my Fuseki running as well with exactly the same data loaded. I don't get how I can use RDFlib over this Fuseki data instead of loading it into the separate graph "g".

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need RDFLib for your example.  You can just connect to Fuseki directly over HTTP using SPARQLWrapper.  See the example on the SPARQLWrapper page to get started.